# User in group can not view products?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configuration, customer

I created a customer group but if I add a customer into this group he does not see any products anymore. If I switch him back to group "general" all products are visible again.

How do I make products visible to a customer group?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the price indexes after creating the customer group?

Comment: Well, no. I worked hard on ignoring the info box about that. Can you post this as an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to jump into this but I have a similar problem. I created a new customer group but only some products were showing for customers in that group. I run the re-index processes from the back-end but the price re-index got stuck in processing state for one week. After deleting the mentioned customer group the re-index processes got back to normal. @davidalger, I read somewhere that the price columns for this new customer may need to be created manually. I'm running Mag 1.7.0.2, could you shade any lights on whether I should go into the tables and create those columns?

Comment: @Andre I am running the same version and I did not need to create extra columns. Try reindexing prices from console `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price`. Also have a look at logging. If reindexing fails you should get an error somewhere. Maybe you need to repair the mysql table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to this problem is most likely going to be re-building the price index. Without building the price index, or saving each product individually, there will be no price index values for the new customer group.

In the `catalog_product_index_price` table you'll find that there is a row per product for each customer group. These indexes are joined onto the product collection in a way which causes the products to not display on the listing pages where the indexes have not been built.

Building the price index will build these records for all products and customer groups, allowing the products to be displayed to customers belonging to the new group.

Comment: Simply superb...